# Google script grant sharing access WITH the EXPIRATION DATE

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a app script to grant view access to my google doc and sharing will expiry in an hour.  Do anyone have a hint ? I don't want to write another script to run every hour to revoke the rights. Is there a better way ? I understand there is an option we can put when granting access manually but I want to do it all inside google script.

Thanks
James

don't really know and search from Internet and even POE couldn't give me an answer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.